# Should I listen for IPv6 connections on a separate port than IPv4?

Tags: c, networking, ipv6, sockets

I have a program that listens for connections and handles them. I am aware that many networking stacks support accepting IPv4 and IPv6 connections over the same socket/port, but I've also heard that Windows XP isn't one of those. In the interest of having the same code run well on all platforms, should I just listen for IPv6 connections on a separate port?

Comment: Why don't you just bind two v6 and v4 sockets with the same port number? This is not a complicated concept.

Comment: @Jeremy - If you are talking about putting both IPv4 and IPv6 traffic over the same port, that won't work in XP.  It works fine in Vista and Windows 7 but XP can't handle it (as per Microsoft's explanation listed below).

Comment: That is still not correct as far as I can tell. All the article is saying is on XP you need to bind AF_INET and AF_INET6 at the same time to support both v4 and v6 on the same port, unlike other OSes where you can support v4 and v6 on a single AF_INET6 socket via v4 mapped addresses. (Unless I’m misreading, which is entirely possible.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows XP SP2+ implements `dual-stack IP` architecture. That means that you can have two sockets (one for AF_INET and another one for AF_INET6 family) which are bound to the same port number. This works quite fine.

**Note**: if your intention was to have a single socket to handle both IPv4 and IPv6 connections then you depend on the so called `dual IP layer stack` architecture implemented in Windows Vista and later (in this case you'll have to disable `IPV6_V6ONLY` options on that socket).

Refer to [Microsoft's Objectives for IP Version 6](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726949.aspx)

Check also general recomendations in [Application Aspects of IPv6 Transition (RFC 4038)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4038.txt) .

*PS: currently accepted answer by BiggsTRC is generally inaccurate as explained in the corresponding comments. However, if you are Ok with using two port numbers - then that answer still makes perfect sense.*

*PS2: I used terminology from the linked article. Not sure if any other platform uses this kind of separation between `dual-stack` and `dual-layer` terms.*

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to be compatible with the XP platform, the simplest answer is to listen on two separate ports.  If you want to get complicated, you could probably do OS detection and determine ports at runtime or something but that seems overly complicated when simply having two ports will solve the issue.

Here is a link with more information on IPv6 and XP:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513665(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Could I get an explanation on the -1?

Comment: That page is telling you that you cannot make a single socket dual-stack on XP/2003.  It is *not* telling you that they have to have different port numbers.